# Breakpoints don't work in Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Breakpoints don't work in Xcode 4.6.3
Please help me

Comment: wait, what?! What are you talking about and why the all caps?

Comment: check flag in bulid setting Generate Debug Symbols is YES if it is No than your debug is not working even though your application is in debug mode. also check flag Strip Debug Symbols During Copy is yes

Answer (score 4):

Breakpoints can be turned off/on in the workspace toolbar.
Breakpoints can be enabled/disabled individually.

Ensure the breakpoints you need are enabled and breakpoints are turned on.

Also take a look here for the reference docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html